# How to disable solr logging with SolrJ?

Tags: unit-testing, maven, logging, solr, solrj

I am using SolrJ for the purposes of an embedded solr server for my unit tests.

The problem is that my maven output is littered with solr logs that I don't really want. For example, I am purposefully triggering a bad query as part of my test. My test passes, but it's very hard to see that because the screen is filled with Solr errors.

I'm not clear how to get around this with SolrJ. I'd like to do this as part of my POM file so that if a test fails, a dev can edit the POM to expose more information.

EDIT:

Solr is instantiated this way:

```
System.setProperty("solr.solr.home", "solr/")
def coreInitter = new CoreContainer.Initializer()
def core = coreInitter.initialize()
this.server = new EmbeddedSolrServer(core, "")
```

Comment: Perhaps some sample code and sample error output would help.

Comment: I just want to turn off logging in SolrJ's embedded server so that Maven doesn't show it.

Comment: I suspect your issue is caused by have 2 active logging implementations configured at the same time. What logging framework have you configured? This is where a copy of your POM file would really help.....

Comment: I have no logging framework configured. I've put the solr code in my original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Solr wiki explains that [SLF4J](http://www.slf4j.org/) is the logging framework used by versions > 1.4

- http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrLogging

You have not provided the POM dependencies of your project so I've made up my own:

```
<project>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.myspotontheweb.demo</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
               <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
               <version>3.6.1</version>
               <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
               </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
               <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
               <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
               <version>3.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

This has the following dependency tree:

```
$ mvn dependency:tree
..
..
[INFO] com.myspotontheweb.demo:demo:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] +- org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.codehaus.woodstox:wstx-asl:jar:3.2.7:runtime
[INFO] |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.6.1:compile
[INFO] \- org.apache.solr:solr-core:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-core:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-analyzers:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-highlighter:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-kuromoji:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-memory:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-misc:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-phonetic:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-queries:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO]    |  \- jakarta-regexp:jakarta-regexp:jar:1.4:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spatial:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-spellchecker:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- org.apache.lucene:lucene-grouping:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.6:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-fileupload:commons-fileupload:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO]    +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
[INFO]    +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:r05:compile
[INFO]    \- javax.servlet:servlet-api:jar:2.4:compile
```

None of these is a logging implementation jar. You'll notice that "jcl-over-slf4j" has been added by SolrJ to ensure that commons logging API calls are redirected to SLF4J.

To completely disable SLF4J logging, add the special NOP dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.1</version>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

Note the scope declaration. Logging implementation jars are not needed for compiling your code, and can cause problems if another project were to use your project's POM.